# Form doesn't work in Safari and Chrome, but does work in ie and firefox

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, safari

this is my first post on this forum. So hi!

I have a problem. I've created an online tool for mystery shoppers to encode and validate visits they have don all over europe. So far, my automatically generated forms based on php and mysql data works great. I have one recurring problem. The forms works great in ie (all versions) and firefox, but not in chrome or safari.

I have used jquery validation on the forms so maybe there's a problem with that.

The problem:
When I work in Safari, nothing happens if I click on submit the form?
When I work in Chrome, the jquery validation works great, but the form doesn't submit?!?

My form start and end tags:

```
<form action="encodage_finish.php" method="post" id="encodageForm">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="<?php echo $translation["SubBodyFormButton"]; ?>" id="verzendknop" /></form>
```

My jquery code:

```
$("#encodageForm").validate({

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('div.error').toggle('normal');
        dateISO: true;
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what this is:

```
dateISO: true;
```

It looks like a validation rule slipped in there on a copy/paste, just remove that as it's invalid script:

```
$("#encodageForm").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('div.error').toggle('normal');
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Currently because of that `dateISO: true;` the browsers that aren't working are blowing up when reading that line in the submit handler, depending on how the browser works, some are blowing up when loading your script initially, others when executing `submitHandler` for the first time.

Comment: Hi Nick the dateISO is for my date-field. DateISO is the european notation for date. This checks of the value is in european format. Is this in the wrong place?

Comment: Hi Nick, I've commented that line out, it changes nothing with my form so it keeps commented out. But submit tests without this line of code, still don't work in safari and chrome.

Comment: @Jens - That line of code should be in `rules`, for example `$("#encodageForm").validate({ rules { dateInputNAME: { dateISO: true } }, submitHandler: ....`

Comment: @Jens - Check your console for the other errors, this is undoubtedly throwing an error, always check the console for them first, if you're unaware how, in Chrome: Ctrl+Shift+I, click the console tab.